# Using UIMotionEffect on my view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to move an object when users tilt screen , but I don't know why my code doesn't work ! Did I miss something ? here is my code :

```
- (void)createMotionEffect:(UIView*)view {

    NSLog(@"itWorks");

    //motion background
    // Set vertical effect
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect =
    [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
     initWithKeyPath:@"center.y"
     type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

    // Set horizontal effect
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect =
    [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc]
     initWithKeyPath:@"center.x"
     type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-50);
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(50);

    // Create group to combine both
    UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
    group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];

    // Add both effects to your view
    [view addMotionEffect:group];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self createMotionEffect:_trex];

}
```

I am testing on iPad Air , iOS 8.4.1 . It works on an iPhone but not on my iPad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count on motion effects to work. The user can turn them off (which may be what's happened to you: you may have turned this feature off on your iPad Air). Or it might not do these effects; not all hardware does.

In any case it sounds like you're misusing this feature. Motion effects should be confined to the parallax effect typical of alerts and the icons in the device's home view. The way to move a view when the user tilts the device is to detect the tilting of the device (with Core Motion) and move the view in response! Do not misuse motion effects as a cheap way to avoid doing the real work here. Do the work.

Comment: Good answer ! thank you I was turning on Reduce motion ! thanks . I turn it off and it works !